# Can you give example about prophecies that have and haven't been fulfilled?

Tags: prophecy

Is it true that there are 735 prophecies in the bible of which 81 % have been fulfilled literally and 19% not yet? This fact is from David Pawson( Old testament revealed )  Can you give example about prophecies that have and haven't been fulfilled?
For example I think below is one that has not been fulfilled yet.

> Now learn a parable of the fig tree(Israel?); When his branch is yet tender, and putteth forth leaves, ye know that summer is nigh: 
>   So likewise ye, when ye shall see all these things(v.4-30), know that it is near, even at the doors. [it: or, he] 
>   Verily I say unto you, This generation(which sees "these things") shall not pass, till all these things be fulfilled. - math.24:32-35

Comment: Who or what will fulfill the prophecies? Jesus?

Comment: @Anonymous: Can you give another verb for "fullfill". I think this is common verb to use when you say that "prophecy is been fullfilled".

Comment: An equivalent of the word 'fulfill' as in 'fulfilling dreams' is 'realize'. Example: I realized my wishes. My wishes came to reality. My wishes were being made real.

Comment: Be advised that several prophecies are types and have dual fulfillment.

Comment: This is a bit broad. Entire books are written on this subject. It would be impossible to provide a complete answer in the StackExchange format, and [a question that invites a list of equally valid, but different answers doesn't fit the StackExchange model, either.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124450/what-is-the-definition-of-a-list-question/124489#124489)

Comment: Is this QA-forum for all who want to ask questions or is it for those who want to discuss about question or is it for those who want to ask questions, but don't know how to formulate it so that it is fit for forum? I mean that how to change this question so that it would be fit for this forum without changing the answers I need. I need an example of few prophecies that are about end times, which has not yet come to past and prophecies that has come to past. I have also a need to formulate question so that it is fit for forum, but it is difficult for me.

Comment: Yes, much too broad. Each denomination has there own opinions on this. From my studies, the SDA's probably have the most opinions on connecting historical events with prophecies, especially those in Daniel and Revelation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example that you gave, the *lesson from a fig tree* (Mathew 24:32-35) is actually already fulfilled in 1948, if we assert that the fig tree here represents the nation of  Israel, because the nation of Israel was reborn in 1948. After the destruction of Israel in AD 70 by the Roman Empire, after wandering around the world for almost 2000 years, the Jewish people could once again claim their land and the long lost nation of Israel was reborn.

If you want to know prophecies in the Bible which are yet to be fulfilled, the best place to find them is the Book of Revelation. Some of the pending prophecies yet to be fulfilled are -

1. **The Rapture:** The faithful will be caught up in the clouds. (1 Thess 4:16-17) *If this prophecy had already happened, then we are the unlucky ones who are left behind to be tormented by the Antichrist.* :-)
2. **The rebuilding of the Temple in Jerusalem**: Some Bible scholars say that the Third Temple in Jerusalem will be built in the last days. (Daniel 9:27, 2 Thess 2:4) This has not happened yet. The Western wall/Wailing wall still stands in Jerusalem and no progress of rebuilding it yet.
3. **The fall of Babylon:** Usually identified as the false religion who will initially control the Beast. Also called the whore, who sits on seven hills. (Rev 17-18)
4. **The Antichrist:** The Beast who will enforce the number 666 and controls all economies. (Rev 13)
5. **The two witnesses:** They will proclaim the truth about the Messiah, killed by the Beast in Jerusalem and resurrected by God after 3 days. (Rev 11)
6. **The Tribulation:** Followers of Christ will be killed by the Antichrist. (Rev 7)
7. **Armageddon:** The last world war to be fought, probably world war III. (Rev 16:16)
8. **The wrath of God:** The wicked people on earth punished by plagues, catastrophes etc. (Rev 16)
9. **The second coming:** Jesus will come back as the *Rider on the White Horse* to defeat the Beast and the kings of the earth. (Rev 19:11-21)
10. **The 1000 years:** Jesus will rule the earth while Satan is in the abyss. (Rev 20:1-6)
11. **The Judgement Day:** Satan and anyone whose name is not in the Book of life will be thrown into the *Lake of Fire*. (Rev 20:11-15)
12. **New Heaven and Earth:** The last thing that the Bible mentions about the destiny of the faithful believers. (Rev 21)

etc.  etc.

Comment: Please consider adding passages to your list to support the prophecies

Comment: Just something to ponder.  How could #12 come true or not?  Where does the line of being taken literal being and end?  I guess I am asking, do you really believe there is a literal book of life which will be thrown into the lake of fire?  If not, what has to happen for that specific prophecy to come true?

Comment: It does not claim that book of life will be thrown, but those whose name is not in it.

Comment: @Mawia. I mean that promise that this generation, which sees all these things(v.4-30) will not pass until all these things happen. I think it is promise and prophecy.

Comment: By the way it dawned on me that when you pray "thy will be done in earth as it is in heaven" you use same meaning for "be done" as for "fullfill". I mean that when prophecy comes to pass, then a bit of will of God is been done but not necessarily wise versa. When His will be done on earth as it is in heaven it does not mean that prophecy comes to pass although it can come in special case.

Comment: @DanAndrews Edited as requested.

Comment: @Mawia: Jesus is using metaphor of summer bringing fig trees blossoming likewise when you see these things(in v. 4-30) come to past know that second coming of Christ is at hand. So it is not to be interpreted as parable, but like blossoming fig tree tells that summer is near, so also those who( this generation) see all these things(v.4-30) come to pass. So I think that it is not parable, because it is not told to us what eg. fig tree represents like in parable of sower, where seed is word of God etc. So I think that unless it is told what fig tree means this passage is to taken literally.